# imacros downloading the url address

Tags: imacros

I am trying to record and as I click around a site I want to capture every url address I am landing on.  Is there a way to do this?
Here is an example of my macro:

VERSION BUILD=8021970
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=10051&categoryId=10001&pageView=detailed&urlLangId=-1&beginIndex=0&langId=-1&top_category=10001&top=Y&parent_category_rn=10001&storeId=10154
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=ID:displayForm ATTR=ID:WC_CategoriesSidebarDisplayf_links_2_1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=ID:displayForm ATTR=ID:WC_CategoriesSidebarDisplayf_links_2_1
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=ID:displayForm ATTR=ID:WC_CategoriesSidebarDisplayf_links_2_1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:WC_BreadCrumbTrailDisplay_link_4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=ID:displayForm ATTR=ID:WC_CategoriesSidebarDisplayf_links_2_2
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.meritorpartsonline.com/wcsstore/MeritorStorefrontAssetStore/images/*

Answer (score 0):

Play the macro below and surf the web. It will write every url that you visit, in the ‘dnlUrls.txt’ file. (Stop this macro when you want to finish tracking.)

```
SET !LOOP -9999999
SET urlFolder EVAL("('{{urlAddress}}' != '{{!URLCURRENT}}') ? '*' : 'noSuchFolder';")
SET urlAddress EVAL("('{{urlAddress}}' != '{{!URLCURRENT}}') ? '{{!URLCURRENT}}' : '{{urlAddress}}';")
SET !EXTRACT {{urlAddress}}

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{urlFolder}} FILE=dnlUrls.txt
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am a little confused so I apologize... So I edited my current macros and just added your macro, which when I hit play I got an error about the negative loop - when I made it positive it did work.  But I guess my question is when you say play should I be recording?  Would the pages I am going to fall in between lines 4 and lines 6?  Thanks again

Comment: I didn't write that my macro had to be joined with yours. And now I really don't understand what namely url addresses you want to save. I suggest minimizing your code above and clarifying the question in order to make it evident for me and other helpers.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Your macros works - it captures perfectly only the current page I am on.  However I have about 100 pages to go to where I would like to capture every url like I did in your macro.  So I assumed I would need to record the pages somewhere in the macro for it to know what to capture.  The site I am going to has page 1 of 100 & I would like to click on each page capture the url, click on the next page, capture the url...  I normally would use Python for this but the site is too complex. Thanks and I apologize again if this is too confusing - I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: Your question is too broad and the simple (but probably useless) answer is to write 2 strings after each click (or `URL GOTO`) in your macro: `SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}` and `SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=dnlUrls.txt` and use a loop through the pages taken from a txt-file. If such automation isn't suitable for your issue, you should use one of the Scripting Interfaces for 'iMacros'. (Nevertheless I still don't comprehend why you need a list of the url addresses if you already have a similar one with these 100 pages.)